# Search for a value within a search in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I m totally new to this VBA world and I m just scratching the surface and need any help I can get.

Here is my question 
I m trying to write a code that finds a value (first value)
if value found, start a new search to find a sub value without reaching the address of the second hit on the (first value)  [totally hard to explain so here is the example]

if I have a list of name like the one below

```
    John C
    age       32
    address   bla bla bla
    DOB       1/2/1990

    Marc D
    DOB       1/2/1989      
    age       32            
    address   bla bla bla 2 


    John D
    address   bla bla bla3
    age       48
    DOB   1/2/1970

    David K 
    age       32
    address   bla bla bla 4
    DOB       1/2/1985
```

and I need to achieve the following

1. Search first for all the peoples named John
2. type the name in a different sheet
3. then get the age of each John found
4. type that age in the cell next to the name

I tried out a code but I think it s a bit inaccurate

```
Sub Copy_To_Another_Sheet_1()

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim MyArr2 As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim NewSh As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

MyArr = Array("John")
MyArr2 = Array("Age")
Set NewSh = Sheets("Sheet3")

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1000")
    Rcount = 5

    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

            FirstAddress = Rng.Address

            Do
                Rcount = Rcount + 1
                Rng.Copy NewSh.Range("G" & Rcount)
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
               For J = LBound(MyArr2) To UBound(MyArr2)
                Set Rng2 = .Find(What:=MyArr2(J), _
                            After:=Rng, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng2 Is Nothing Then
                    Rng2.Offset(, 1).Copy NewSh.Range("H" & Rcount)
                End If

                Next J
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress

        End If

    Next I

End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

I used Array here to setup my search parameter because at the final version of that code I need to be able to find a list of name and their relative information.

I keep getting error after I find the first couple values.

Any help is very much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd probably use a different algorithm.  But if your data is only two columns, why is your search range 26 columns wide?  I would probably just reorganize the data, using VBA, into a table that can be filtered and then, in the case you show, filter on "John"

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this refactoring of your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_To_Another_Sheet_1()
    Dim namesArr As Variant, name As Variant
    Dim dataArr As Variant, datum As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim reportSht As Worksheet

    Dim namesRng As Range
    Dim arr As Variant

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    namesArr = Array("John", "Mark")
    dataArr = Array("Age", "Address", "DOB")
    Set reportSht = Sheets("Sheet3")
    rCount = 5 '<--| initialize row index to start writing data from
    With Sheets("Sheet1") '<--| reference "Sheet1"
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A" cells from row 1 down to last non empty one
            For Each name In namesArr '<--| loop through "names" array
                Set namesRng = GetNames(.Cells, name) '<--| collect current name occurrences in referenced cells
                If Not namesRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if any occurrence has been found then...
                    For Each datum In dataArr '<--| ...loop through "data" array
                        arr = GetData(name, namesRng, datum) '<--| collect current "data" occurrences under current name ones
                        If IsArray(arr) Then '<-- if any data has been found then...
                            reportSht.Range("G" & rCount).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr '<-- ... write data in 'reportShtt'
                            rCount = rCount + 1 '<--| update row index to write data in
                        End If
                    Next datum
                End If
            Next name
        End With
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub


Function GetNames(rng As Range, name As Variant) As Range
    Dim f As Range, unionRng As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set unionRng = rng.Resize(1, 1).Offset(, 1)
    With rng
        Set f = .Find(What:=name, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.Address
            Do
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, f)
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
        Set GetNames = Intersect(unionRng, .Cells)
    End With
End Function


Function GetData(name As Variant, rng As Range, datum As Variant) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim data As String

    For Each cell In rng
        Do While cell <> ""
            If UCase(cell) = UCase(datum) Then
                data = data & cell.Offset(, 1) & "|"
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set cell = cell.Offset(1)
        Loop
    Next cell
    If data <> "" Then GetData = Split(name & "|" & Left(data, Len(data) - 1), "|")
End Function
```

Comment: this is actually a very good point here. Although what I am looking for is something a bit dynamic as the sheet will grow with time.
so if I have more than 2 columns but I know exactly the column I need to search in, and I have like a 10 name to be searched in a list of 2000 names would that work ?

Comment: It would. The statement `With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))` sets the column to search the name in, so just change `"A1"` to the first cell of the _real_ column and `, 1` to its corresponding column index (you can also use its literal value, e.g.: `,"A"` in this case). While you set as many "names" as you need in `namesArr = Array(...` . Since I fulfilled your _original_ question please mark as accepted. Thank you

Comment: kindly find below the output of the code as is on the above example


John   32                 125896
John    bla bla bla bla bla bla
John    121990         28

Comment: @KarimDaoud, I don't get it. is the solution working for you? If not, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want. My favorite would be to create a User Defined Object (Class Module) and then just pull out the items I want.  The programming is complex, but there is a lot of flexibility.

Here is another method using Excel's AutoFilter.

- Use the `InputBox` to get the name to filter.  This could also be set in a number of other ways.
- First we reorganize the data into a table we can filter.
- Filter on the selected name, using wild cards so we get anything starting with that name
- Hide the columns we are not interested in
- Copy the visible cells to the top of the worksheet, and clear the table

You could also sort the table by name -- all kinds of things you can do once you have the table.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterList()
    'could set this in many different ways
    'I suggest an input box if it will change frequently
    Dim sName As String

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

sName = InputBox("Enter Search Name")

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet3")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'read source data into array
vSrc = rSrc

'dimension results array
ReDim vRes(0 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rSrc, "DOB"), 1 To 4)

'Results array header
vRes(0, 1) = "Name"
vRes(0, 2) = "Age"
vRes(0, 3) = "Address"
vRes(0, 4) = "DOB"

'Populate the results array
J = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Select Case vSrc(I, 1)
        Case "age"
            vRes(J, 2) = vSrc(I, 2)
        Case "address"
            vRes(J, 3) = vSrc(I, 2)
        Case "DOB"
            vRes(J, 4) = vSrc(I, 2)
        Case ""
            'do nothing
        Case Else 'then it is a name
            J = J + 1
            vRes(J, 1) = vSrc(I, 1)
    End Select
Next I

'Write the results to the worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2)).Offset(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1)
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes

    'Do some formatting
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .Columns(4).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

'Filter and hide unwanted data,
'then copy wanted data to top of sheet
With wsRes
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    With rRes
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & sName & "*"
        .Range(.Columns(3), .Columns(4)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Worksheet.Cells(1, 1)
        .Worksheet.ShowAllData
        .Clear
    End With
    .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End With

End Sub
```

**Results using *John* as the name**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate very much the reply, but what I wanted was something that would work in cases where under each name there is a set of criteria. the amount of criteria under each names is not always the same under each name. I m working really hard to get my head around all the new input I m getting here and I really thank you for the effort :)